# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(1+\sin^2(2x)\right)}{1-\cos^2(x)} $

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

I used all the trig and log tricks but still can't compute this limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(1+\sin^2(2x)\right)}{1-\cos^2(x)}.$$

I tried the following:

\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(1+\sin^2(2x)\right)}{1-\cos^2(x)} 
 &=  \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(1+\sin^2(2x)\right)}{\sin^2(x)} 
\\ &=  \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(1+4\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)\right)}{\sin^2(x)} .\end{align*}

I tried to substitute $\sin^2(x)$ but still wandering.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Which limit?

Comment: Please don't use pictures, use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please [edit the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4372109/edit) to let us know exactly what you've tried. This information can help us determine if you just need a hint or if you're way off base. It also helps people avoid wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or duplicating your efforts.

Comment: Perhaps use $\ln(1+x)\approx x$.

Comment: Yeah, but what did you try?

Comment: Write it as $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+\sin^2(2x))}{\sin^2(2x)}4\cos^2x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:- The Maclaurin Expansion of $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}-....\,,-1<x\leq 1$

This gives $\ln(1+x)=x+O(x^{2})$ . Where $O(.)$ is the [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)

Can you use this now? . Try replacing $x$ with $4\sin^{2}(x)\cos^{2}(x)$.

Another hint:- It is well known that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$$.

Then $$\lim_{x\to 0} 4\cos^{2}(x)\frac{\ln(1+4\sin^{2}(x)\cos^{2}(x))}{4\sin^{2}(x)\cos^{2}(x)}$$. Can you now see the similarity between the two expressions above? . If yes then what can you say by product rule of limits?

Comment: I was just about to give my hint using the series expansion as well, oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Just using the standard limit $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+t)}{t} = 1$ you get

\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{\ln\left(1+\sin^2(2x)\right)}{1-\cos^2(x)}
& = & \frac{\ln\left(1+\sin^2(2x)\right)}{\sin^2(2x)}\cdot \frac{\sin^2(2x)}{\sin^2 x} \\
& = & 4\cos^2 x \cdot  \frac{\ln\left(1+\sin^2(2x)\right)}{\sin^2(2x)} \\
& \stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow} & 4\cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 4
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

We know that (by asymptotic relations):
$$\ln(1+f(x)) \sim f(x)\;\;\; x \to \alpha \;\; f(x) \to 0$$
Also:
$$\sin(x) \sim t \;\; x \to 0$$
And:
$$\cos(x) \sim 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 \;\; x \to 0$$

So, your limit is going to be:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(1+\sin^2(2x)\right)}{1-\cos^2(x)}\;\;\sim \;\;\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2(2x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}\;\;\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4x^2}{1-\cos^2(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4x^2}{(1+\cos(x))\cdot(1-\cos(x))}\;\; \lim_{x\to0}\frac{4x^2}{2\cdot\frac{1}{2}x^2}=4$$